# unsetting env. variable before a command

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

In my `zsh` I have set the environment variable `PAGER` to `less`. However in mercurial this environment variable takes precedence over [specifying a pager in its config file](https://repo.mercurial-scm.org/hg/help/pager) and I ultimately want a different pager than `less` but settled for making an alias for `hg` that **sets** the options for `less`:

```
alias hg='LESS=FXRS hg'
```

What I initially tried, and failed to accomplish is unsetting `PAGER` by doing:

```
alias hg='PAGER= hg'
```

But that doesn't unset PAGER, and mercurial doesn't fall back to using the value in its config file.

I would prefer to set the pager in mercurial's global config file. But I also don't want to remove PAGER completely, as it is used by other programs as well.

Is there a way to unset an environment variable for a single command, as there is a way to set it for a single command?